# Importing mysql database from java code

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

**This code do restore mysql tables but application almost goes into sleep(20min plus). and my database Routines do not come in mysql workbench, can somebody tell me what is the actual solution?**

```
public static boolean restoreDB(String dbName, String dbUserName, String dbPassword, String source) {

    String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysql", "--user=" + dbUserName, "--password=" + dbPassword, "-e", "source \"D:/khokher/mydb.sql\""};

    Process runtimeProcess;
    try {

        runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

        if (processComplete == 0) {
            System.out.println("Backup restored successfully");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Could not restore the backup");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual problem?

Comment: Johnny Graber, i think this is the problem of importing mysql routine i guess mysql is dependent on its routines and we also need to make routines dump while creating backup of databases and for that there should be a different mysql backup query.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `Runtime.exec` method, you have to read the output from the process it creates. Otherwise the process fills its output buffer and stops to wait until you empty the buffer by reading the output.

To read the output from a process you get the input streams from the `Process` object that  `exec` returned. You can read the standard output from the stream returned by `getInputStream` and the standard error from the stream returned by `getErrorStream`.

If you can, use the [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) library. It makes launching an external processes and handling its input and output easier.

Comment: it seems nice information, but problem is my dump query is not generating routines i can import only tables and view.

Comment: `mysql` prints error messages, if there are any, to its output. You need to read the output to find if there were any errors. So the `mysql` command actually finishes after running for 20 minutes? What is the exit code?

Comment: command do not finishes exactly after 20 min it do take more than this i guess never finishes but it do restore the data base after 20 min i made few changes in above code and now only problem is this it keep me waiting. and i m not using exit code