# When I run pg_restore via process in java application, application freeze

Tags: java, swing, postgresql

When I run `pg_restore` via process in java application, application freeze and info message don't show, but process successfully finished. Why it so? I use PostgreSQL 9.2.

Method's code:

```
private void restoreDB() {

    JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();   
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("DB FILES", "sql");
    fileopen.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
    fileopen.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:/backups/"));
    fileopen.setDialogTitle("Выберите папку для резервной копии");
    fileopen.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    fileopen.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);   
    int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Restore DB");                
    if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println(path);
            String user = "postgres";
            String dbName = "Auto";
            String executeCmd = "pg_restore -i -U " + user + " -d " + dbName+" -v "+ path;
            Process runtimeProcess;
            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

            if (processComplete == 0) {
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfull!");
                log.info("Successfull!");
            } else {
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unsuccessfully");
                log.info("Unsuccessfully");
            }
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson That so needs to be an answer

Comment: I found answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732403/database-restoring-with-java-code-program-not-responding 
Thanks for answers!    Problem with output from the process. "Otherwise the process fills its output buffer and stops to wait until you empty the buffer by reading the output."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.